# Calculating date difference with timespan and future dates

Tags: vb.net, datetime, datediff

I am trying to flag rows in a grid in the following order based on a date column

- When 2 or more days old from today
  then RED
- When 1 day old then YELLOW
- When 0 days old then GREEN
- When the date is in the future then
  BLUE

I have the following which is working fine except for the future dates which are GREEN instead of BLUE.

```
 Dim myDate As DateTime = CType(grdSummaryView.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "myDate"), DateTime)

 Select Case Now.Subtract(myDate).Days
                '2 or more days old then RED FLAG
                Case Is >= 2
                    e.Value = ImageCollection2.Images(3)
                Case 1
                '1 day old then YELLOW FLAG
                    e.Value = ImageCollection2.Images(1)
                Case 0
                'Current day then GREEN FLAG
                    e.Value = ImageCollection2.Images(0)
                Case Else
                    e.Value = ImageCollection2.Images(4)
 End Select
```

Comment: Days will return 0 unless you are at least 24 hours in the future? So if it is 2010/08/15 12:30:00 and your future date is 2010/08/16 0:30:00 then I believe the TimeSpan is -00:12:00:00 etc no?

Comment: I tried CASE < 0 but that didn't work either.

Comment: Could be... if that's the case, just adding .Date to both the myDate assignment and the Select Case should do it.

Comment: @Saif, does "one day old" mean "In to the prior day" or "24+ hours"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might suggest an alternate way of writing the code:

```
Dim age As Double = Now.Substract(myDate).TotalDays

If age >= 2 Then
  e.Value = ImageCollection2.Images(3) //Red
ElseIf age >= 1 Then
  e.Value = ImageCollection2.Images(1) //Yellow
ElseIf age >= 0 Then
  e.Value = ImageCollection2.Images(0) //Green
Else
  e.Value = ImageCollection2.Images(4) //Blue
End If
```

As mentioned in my initial comments, Days will return 0 unless you are at least 24 hours in the future. So if it is 2010/08/15 12:30:00 and your future date is 2010/08/16 0:30:00 then the TimeSpan is -00:12:00:00 etc and Days will be 0.

Comment: I am going by dates only in DB. Yours is more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

The .Days always gives an Integer value so it won't work until you are at least 24 hours into the future. You can either solve it as you suggested yourself or work immediately with the Timespan difference.

You also might want to consider the meaning of this difference. Does 2 days old mean that you want to select elements that were created 48 hours ago or does it mean all entries made on the 10th of November for instance.

Comment: +1 for identifying the issue with Days; as mentioned in the comments, seeking "hours"

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

I first wrap my CASE with a IF using Date.Compare to first check if the date is in the future.

```
If Date.Compare(myDate, Now) < 0 Then
                Select Case Now.Subtract(delivDate).Days

                    Case Is >= 2
                        '2 or more days old then RED FLAG
                        e.Value = ImageCollection2.Images(3)
                    Case 1
                        '1 day old then YELLOW FLAG
                        e.Value = ImageCollection2.Images(1)
                    Case Else
                        '0 day (current day) then GREEN FLAG
                        e.Value = ImageCollection2.Images(0)
                End Select
            Else
                'DATE IS IN THE FUTURE
                e.Value = ImageCollection2.Images(4)
            End If
```